# Problems on SVN commit

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am using eclipse neon. I canceled one SVN commit due to bad network (force quit). But now, when I tried to commit those files again I'm getting exception saying ,

**org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E155004: Working copy 'XXXX...' locked**

When I tried *Team -> cleanup*  it failed due to same locking issue. Tried *svn cleanup* from terminal. Then I got "bash: svn: command not found..".

Is there any way to change this lock issue?

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127932/working-copy-xxx-locked-and-cleanup-failed-in-svn, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865932/why-do-i-keep-getting-svn-working-copy-xxxx-locked-try-performing-cleanup

Answer (score 1):

Seems you tried svn cleanup on Cygwin on Windows OS.

You can try this,

Go to the directory (not in Eclipse) where the files are, go into the .svn dir and delete the file called lock. Error : Attempted to lock an already-locked dir svn: Working copy 'C:\work\myproject\workspaces\HPDP' locked