# commit failed in svn : some file have been locked

Tags: eclipse, svn, commit

When I was committing my project in svn I've got error that some project have been locked. I also tried to clean up my project but I've got the same error message: [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I keep getting 'SVN: Working Copy XXXX locked; try performing 'cleanup'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865932/why-do-i-keep-getting-svn-working-copy-xxxx-locked-try-performing-cleanup)

Comment: Hum... What is that file `maven.148350921313`? Is that familiar to you?