# Cleanup Failed To Process The Following Paths

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

My problem is the same as the one here:

[Working copy XXX locked and cleanup failed in SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127932/svn-working-copy-xxx-locked-and-cleanup-failed)

However, the solution that seemed to work for everyone there isn't working for me.  Trying to checkout to a new folder doesn't work for me.  I really don't want to have to delete the project out of the repository and replace it to make it work.

I am using TortoiseSvn.  Anyone have any more ideas that weren't suggested in the other question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured it out:  I wasn't cleaning up the root directory... when I cleaned up the directory above the one with the issue then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
svn revert -R *
```

-R for recursive
* for all changes