# XCode SVN clean up

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

I am using SVN with XCode to maintain a svn repositery. Earlier it was working fine. Last night my internet connection was broken while Committing the code to svn and since then its giving an error like **svn: Working copy 'Path here' locked** and **svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)**. Now my issue is i am not able to find any way to Cleanup from xcode. Is it possible to cleanup from xcode ? If Yes then how and if its not then how can we clean up using terminal.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow these steps for Cleanup

1. Open terminal.
2. Write **cd prj_path**  [**Note**: prj_path is the path of your working copy]
3. Now write **svn cleanup**.

See the terminal commands here.

```
c31:~ c31$ cd /Volumes/Data/Projects/test 
c31:test c31$ svn cleanup
```

Comment: So @Bhargavi we cann't simply clean up svn Repositery through Xcode ?

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your reply. I will definitely try it.

Comment: @βhargavḯ I know this answer is correct but for some reason, I'm still getting the same error whenever I'm trying to commit the source code files again. :-( Any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Solve it this way:

```
Copy edited items to another location.
Delete the folder containing the problem path.
Update the containing folder through Subversion.
Copy your files back.
Commit
```

Look at this post: [Working copy XXX locked and cleanup failed in SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127932/working-copy-xxx-locked-and-cleanup-failed-in-svn)