# When SVN Clean up command execute using C# SharpSVN

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

I am using SharpSVN C# for my application.

Got working copy path locked " error for my working directory" don't know why.

So on which condition cleanup command should execute in this C # code?

Or how do I check if my working dir is locked or not ok?

Comment: Probably one of the 55 answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127932/working-copy-xxx-locked-and-cleanup-failed-in-svn?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Working copy XXX locked and cleanup failed in SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127932/working-copy-xxx-locked-and-cleanup-failed-in-svn)

Comment: No, I need to execute Clean command by sharpsvn in c# but before this how i can check my working dir lock or not